# Best practices bootstrapping new Ansible servers with the root account

Tags: ansible

When booting up a new server, if root is the primary account created, what is the best practice to handle running as root the first time a playbook runs vs running it as ansible after my script sets up its service own account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever process you have to provision privileged service accounts. This is not Ansible specific, and may be a different implementation depending on operating system. Several approaches exist:

- Create a user at instance install or first boot.
- Join to a directory or other central identity that already contains the users.
- Install and run ansible locally on managed nodes, bypassing the need for ssh. Possibly as root from cron. See ansible-pull for an example script.
- ssh in as root. Controversial, many sshd configurations deny root login.

Answer (score 1):

Create the ansible service account and install the ssh public key at install time.

I have this scripted in my kickstart scripts:

```
%post --erroronfail
# Set up ansible user
useradd -rm ansible
echo "ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/ansible
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/ansible
mkdir -m 700 /home/ansible/.ssh
echo "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIFsW/fNKMjMQjkYcQOqwD14UItgMBGIX7HHpP2YTvQkI ansible" > /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R ansible.ansible /home/ansible/.ssh
%end
```